# Loading multiple truffle artifacts from a single sol file

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

Big picture: How do I get multiple contract instances from a single sol file using truffle-contract?

I have two Contracts in my .sol file  (it's more of a contract factory)

```
const artifacts = require('../build/contracts/Contract.json');
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const MyContract = contract(artifacts);
```

How do create an instance of the 2nd contract using truffle-contract?
when i'm testing in mocha i can do

```
const SecondContract = artifacts.require("SecondContract");
```

but for some reason in truffle exec i get

```
TypeError: artifacts.require is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using truffle javascript testing and you have a good understanding of mocha. Then you can easily create more instances of the same contract. So your syntax to create a new instance of a truffle contract should be.

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
    let SecondContract = await Contract.new()
})
```

Alternatively, perhaps you are asking a much simpler question that I imagined. When truffle artifacts are created for a single `.sol` file containing multiple contracts (such as in inherhitance), multiple artifacts are created (check the folder `build/contracts/`), try the following code snippet.

```
const artifacts = require('../build/contracts/Contract.json');
const SecondContract = require('../build/contracts/SecondContract.json')
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const MyContract = contract(artifacts);
const myCoolContract = contract(SecondContract)
```

Perhaps you are missing a callback which is why truffle exec is not working as expected.

See https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/writing-external-scripts

Comment: Oh my... i didn't notice that there was another json for the other contract.   Thank you very much.